# pymongo 3.2: ConnectionFailure not working

Tags: python, pymongo

I'm pulling my hair out trying to get pymongo to error out when code can't connect to a MongoD instance.  It seems like no matter what I do the 'pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure' is not working.  I've tried this on localhost and a remote mongoD instance.  When I use the mongoclient shell ('mongo --host xx.xx.xx.xx') from the same system, I get the proper 'connection refused'.  Other exceptions are working, but not 'ConnectionFailure.'  Note that when I run tshark sniffer on mongod instance host, I see the proper TCP RST on closed port for connection refused.  Mongod is not listening, but the pymongo ConnectionFailure can't catch a failed connection.

python version:  2.7.10
pymongo version:  3.2

What could I be missing, or steps to troubleshoot?  In this example below, mongod is not running on localhost.  I also stop it on  remote host.  In both instances, the exception error is not caught, and pymongo code appears to think it is connected.

Code:

```
import pymongo
try:
    pymongo.MongoClient('localhost:27017')
except pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure, e:
    print "Could not connect: %s" % e
```

Comment: Are you able to connect to the MongoDB using `mongo` shell?

Comment: No, the response is connection refused.

Comment: So at first you should make sure that the MongoDB is running properly...

Comment: mongod is not supposed to run.  The pymongo code is not catching the exception for ConnectionFailure.  Not sure what else I can check because MongoD should not be running.

Comment: I can get mongo shell and pymongo to connect just fine.  I don't think you're understanding my question.  It is that when it is NOT running, the code can't detect a connection failure.  The reason I need this is detailed and granular detection of failed connection.

Comment: If `mongod` is not running you do not have an DB instance to connect to. Connecting to an database at an unavailable host would raise a connection error for sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First attempt: Syntax error**

You got an syntax error in your code. Change:

```
pymongo.MongoClient('localhost':27017)
```

into:

```
pymongo.MongoClient('localhost:27017')
```

or something like this:

```
pymongo.MongoClient(host='localhost', port=27017)
```

You had the single quote at the wrong place.

---

**Working sample snippet using Python 3.4.3 and pymongo 2.9**

```
import pymongo

try:
    pymongo.MongoClient('localhost:27017')
except pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure as e:
    print(e)
```

---

**After reading the [Pymongo3 migration guide](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/migrate-to-pymongo3.html#pymongo-3-migration-guide)**

I think this behaviour is as desired since the [guide](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/migrate-to-pymongo3.html#mongoclient-connects-asynchronously) tells:

> In PyMongo 3, the MongoClient constructor no longer blocks while
>   connecting to the server or servers, and it no longer raises
>   `ConnectionFailure` if they are unavailable, nor `ConfigurationError` if
>   the user’s credentials are wrong. Instead, the constructor returns
>   immediately and launches the connection process on background threads.
>   The connect option is added to control whether these threads are
>   started immediately, or when the client is first used.

As shown in the migration guide something like this should work:

> ```
> from pymongo.errors import ConnectionFailure
> client = MongoClient(connect=False)
> try:
>     result = client.admin.command("ismaster")
> except ConnectionFailure:
>     print("Server not available")
> ```

Comment: Darn, that doesn't fix it.  I wish it did.  The only difference is you are running Python 3.4.3 and I'm running 2.7.  Are you saying you get the ConnectionFailure response, or it does connect?

Comment: I could both connect to a running database on port 27017 and handle a ConnectionFailure when trying to connect on port 12345.

Comment: Ok, progress here, but I still don't understand.  This code does work.  It seems ConnectionFailure only works for me when I add the handle to the DB and try to authenticate.  This works:

Comment: @albertThanks for testing.  What version of pymongo and python are you running?  I guess you've done a sanity check that my code is right, must be something else.

Comment: My bad, you had said that above.  Thought you were a different user.  Well the only thing I can think is to try with Python 3.4 instead of 2.7.  If you see my other answer, I got it working to do ConnectionFailure, but only when I get the DB and also try to authenticate.

Comment: Is there any known issue with pymongo behaving differently between python 2.7 and 3.x?

Comment: I just installed pymongo 3.2 (Python 3.4.3) in an virtual environment and the Connection Error is not caught properly.

Comment: Thanks Albert.  So it is the pymongo version.  Should this be reported to pymongo team as a bug?

Comment: If you would be so nice. Otherwise I would do this since I thought about update my production system in a few ways - thank god I didn't yet.

Comment: It seems like that is known and desired as stated in the migration manual: https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/migrate-to-pymongo3.html#mongoclient-connects-asynchronously

Comment: Glad you didn't as well, ha.  Thanks for this valuable information.  I was googling for this and missed the migration guide.  I can now adjust code for non-blocking behavior in my code.

Comment: If this solved your question please tick my answer in order to mark your question as solved.

Comment: I ticked the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: The tick should show up now on your answer.  It is a check mark and it is now green.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

```
def dbConnect():
    try:
        conn = pymongo.MongoClient(<connection URL>)
        try:
            conn.server_info()
            return "Connection Successfull"
        except OperationFailure as e:
            return e
    except Exception as e:
        return e

print (dbConnect())
```

As MongoClient Doesn't return a valuable response that can help in connectin state this will work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I am also facing this problem while using `pymongo.MongoClient()`.

Try this code below, it might help you:

```
def initiateDbConnection():
        try:
            dbConnection= pymongo.MongoClient(<connection URL>)
            try:
                dbConnection.server_info()
                return "Connection Established"
            except OperationFailure as err:
                return err
        except Exception as err:
            return err
    print (initiateDbConnection())
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work only when I add two more lines to get the database and authenticate.  I don't know why.  Shouldn't ConnectionFailure catch the error only when you try to connect?

```
try:
    dbconn = pymongo.MongoClient(host, port)
    db = dbconn[dbname]
    success = db.authenticate(user, password)

except pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure as msg:
    print "Failed connection: %s" % str(msg)
```

When I watch this with a sniffer on a host that isn't running mongod, it attempts to connect for 20-30 seconds, and then the pymongo host prints:

'Failed connection: host.db.com:27017: [Errno 61] Connection refused'

Answer (score 0):

For those who come in the future, this is how we solved our issue with this error, after a day of troubleshooting

I have a Flask project, connecting to MongoDb using Python 3.9.6, pymongo 3.12.0, flask 2.0.1, and flask-pymongo 2.3.0.

My connection string looked like this: `mongodb+srv://my_username:my_user@cluster0.abc123.mongodb.net/my_db_name?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

My initialization of the connection in `app.py` looked like this:

```
    app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "mongodb+srv://my_username:my_user@cluster0.abc123.mongodb.net/my_db_name?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
    mongo = PyMongo(app)
    db = mongo.db
    print("db initialization complete")
```

After trying to read or write to the DB without success, yet receiving no errors, I added a try/except like this:

```
try:
            myCollection = db["collectionName"]
            result = myCollection.find({}) # returns all documents
            print("after query", result)
            print("after query, again", list(result))
        except Exception as err:
            print("Error in query_db -> ", err)
```

I was then able to see the error that was occurring. It was a timeout due to a connection failure.

```
Error in query_db -> cluster0.nt7lk.mongodb.net:27017: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 6124a7768a437d2f7c01cdcf, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('cluster0.nt7lk.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('cluster0.nt7lk.mongodb.net:27017: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')>]>
```

After spending another hour trying to figure this out, including checking the open IP address and port on the Mongo Compass web portal, making sure the connection string came from the 'Connect via Application' instead of 'Connect via Mongo Compass', and a thousand ways of defining the initialization, I realized that I needed the `dnspython` package in order to use mongo connection strings that include `srv` in them.

Run `pip install -r dnspython` to install it.